# React-navigation parent to child transition

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I want to implement a [parent to child transition](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigational-transitions.html#navigational-transitions-parent-to-child) in a FlatList (in a StackNavigator with a DrawerNavigator as root).

I see react-navigation have custom Transitioner. That could be the way to accomplish that. This [article](http://www.reactnativediary.com/2017/01/23/react-navigation-shared-element-transition-1.html) (april 2017) is a tutorial to do exactly that, but it needs some native customization.

I'm currently in Expo env, so I cannot do it. There is an alternative way to accomplish this transition in react-navigation?